# Azure datasync not updating from hub database

Tags: sql, database, azure, synchronization

In my setup I have 3 databases:

1. On premise database
2. Hub database (azure)
3. Sync database (azure)

The on premise db syncs to the hub (client wins) the hub syncs to the sync db (hub wins).
In my db's 3 tables have changes, 2 only receive inserts, 1 has inserts, deletes and updates.
Most of the time all works well, but sometimes updates to some (not all) records don't work. Once they stop working for a certain record they never work again.
The above problem only occurs on the sync from hub to sync db. Until now the sync from on-premise db to hub is correct.

Until now I solve the issue by removing the table from the sync rules, deleting the contents from teh table and re-adding the table to the sync rules.

The table where the problems occur only has 1 primary key field and this is not the field that needs to be updated.

When I check the sync logs they all state that sync was successful, no errors, no warnings...

Comment: You know that DataSync is still in Preview, right?